# How to create a floating window of selection tools for highlighting regions of a pyqtgraph?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I would like to add some selection tools to a pyqtgraph. The idea is that I would have a floating window on the graph that has for instance a rectangle or a circle tool. Then the user could place the shape on the graph and it would give me the coordinates of the area covered by the shape. Is this possible using pyqtgraph?

To get us started here is a minimal example of how to create a pyqtgraph.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

class Main():
    x = np.arange(1000)
    y = np.random.normal(size=(3, 1000))
    plotWidget = pg.plot(title="Three plot curves")

    r = pg.CircleROI((0.5, 0.5), (1, 1), radius=5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        main = Main()
        sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: I don't know `pyqtgraph` but I think it can be possible but it may nees a lot of code - it may need to catch mouse events and use mouse position to draw circle/retangle in new place (after removing circle/retangle from previous place). But tool like Matplotlib may display plot with toolbar and it may have tools to zoom, etc. - and probably it may have  tool to select region.

Comment: I would start with normal buttons inside window. And later you may try to create separated window (using even `QWidget`) or try to create object directly on plot (but this can be more complex)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It looks like the `ROI` hierachy will do what I want. Still trying to figure out how to use it though -- the above code seems to literall do nothing.

Comment: first it would need `plotWidget.addItem(r)` to show ROI in window. But bigger problem is to process mouse events to move/resize/rotate this ROI. In [introduction](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/introduction.html) (in official documentation) I found `pyqtgraph.examples.run()` which runs window with examples - if you use field `search` to search `region` then it show example code for `ROI` and you can even run it. It uses `app = pg.mkQApp(title)` to create main window - and this window already process mouse events for `ROI`.